# Manipulating df in order to create network data

Tags: r, networking, data-manipulation

I have this example of df:

```
  author other_authors
1      A       D, E ,F
2      B             G
3      C          H, F
```

i need to create an collaboration network from it.

I've read this article on how to do it, but couldn't make it.
https://amirhosblog.wordpress.com/2016/09/29/co-authorship-analysis-in-r/

The df I'm working need to be transformed to something like this:

```
     author    author2 author3 author4
1      A       D       E       F
2      B       G
3      C       H       F
```

and then transformed again into the `edges` and `nodes` df's.

Any ideas on how to do it? I'm really in a hurry here.

Here is the df:

```
df <- structure(list(author = c("A", "B", "C"),
                     other_authors = c("D, E ,F", "G", "H, F")),
                class = "data.frame",
                row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: `library(tidyr);df %>% separate(other_authors, into = paste0("author", 2:4))`

Comment: or use `base R` `cbind(df[1], read.csv(text=df$other_authors, header = FALSE, colClasses = "character", col.names = paste0("author", 2:4)))`